# String with a minus sign passed to a function in python

Tags: python, string

Why is a string with a minus sign not recognised properly when passed to a function in python? The simple code

```
def f(s):
    print(s)
    if s is 'a-b':
        print('I expect this to be printed.')
    else:
        print('Instead, this is printed.')


s = 'a-b'
if s is 'a-b':
    print('Oustide everything is fine.')
f(s)
```

gives the output

```
Oustide everything is fine.
a-b
Instead, this is printed.
```

Can someone explain please why this happens? Without the minus sign everything is fine.

Comment: `is` is not how you do an equality test.

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes here, btw. There isn't enough context for someone unfamiliar with programming to know "what to Google" to downvote this. All we see here is someone doing something reasonable and getting an unexpected answer from the language.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Part of my confusion was because for a string without the minus sign everything worked as expected. So, I thought it has something to do with the minus sign.

Comment: @Alehud if you can, take the time to read through the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Even if it doesn't all make sense, it can give you an idea where to look when things don't work as expected, and it can help you figure out what to Google next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python distinguishes between values that are *equal* and values that are *identical*. You should use the `is` operator rarely. In fact, you probably won't encounter too many cases where you use `is` other than `is None`.

Here, you want `if s == 'a-b':`.